# WPF + MVVM with multi-windows handling

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I was looking at a video that explain pretty well MVVM. However, it seem to only show an one window application model. What do you have to do if you want to handle a multi-windows model ?

From what i see.. the app.xaml is linked to the MainWindow (as DataContext). Since app.xaml is the starting point it execute the MainWindow. The MainWindow have ViewModels as a bind so it can handle his ViewModels.. but all this are only for one windows.. what happen with you want to introduce a second window ? How do you proceed ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate your view (`Window`) type from the main windows view model via a service, injected as an abstraction. You can then set the `DataContext` of this Window programmatically within the service, locate the appropriate view and use `myWindow.Show()` or `myWindow.ShowDialog()` to display the Window. An MVVM framework such as [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) has a `WindowManager` for taking care of the view location and view/view model binding for you.

Comment: Your talking about a WindowManager from a specific framework. But do you think we could handle this with a static class instead which contains the list of Windows ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, but you'll probably want to make it instance based and work against an abstraction such as IWindowManager in your view models, as you'll want to mock things like dialog results in unit tests.

Comment: While this is obviously a workable solution (in the sense that it "works"), this really violates the spirit of MVVM; MVVM is intended to keep the boundary between functionality and UI very distinct, and you blur (if not outright eliminate) that distinction when you start dealing with UI elements within the ViewModel. Another very common practice is to place the ViewModel in another assembly altogether (to help keep this boundary in place), which would not allow you to do this.

Comment: @Adam_Robinson Umm. Yeah you not wrong. Actually by using a WindowManager you somehow bind the ViewModel to the UI which violate the MVVM if that what your talking about ?

Comment: There isn't any coupling between view models and UI elements, as you're working against an abstract window manager whose responsibility it is to instantiate your view types. The view models do not reference the views or their controls.

Comment: @devdigital: "You can instantiate your view (Window) type from the main windows view model". That sounds like pretty tight coupling between the UI (the Window) and the ViewModel. The ViewModel should be responsible for saying that another child ViewModel needs displaying, and it should have a way to indicate that this can be a blocking or non-blocking operation (i.e. modal or non-modal display at the UI level). Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @Rushino: There are a few ways to do what you're asking; the way that I do it uses WPF Behaviors, but I haven't written about it yet and it's a bit too much to go into in a single answer. The various ways of mapping ViewModel to View that are provided by several MVVM/WPF frameworks are all fine, as they all are designed to allow the ViewModel to deal with the ViewModel side only, and the mapping to be made at a lower level. What you *don't* want is to do things like directly instantiate a View object within the ViewModel. This is why it's a good idea to have a dedicated ViewModel assembly.

Comment: Yes probably, I like to introduce ambiguity wherever possible. It keeps me on my toes. I should have said it should instantiate the Window via a service, injected as an abstraction. This is already provided in something like Caliburn.Micro, other MVVM frameworks presumably offer an equivalent. Weirdly, my answer does now say this :)

Comment: I concur with the dedicated assembly idea. I'd be interested in seeing your Behavior approach

Comment: I think i get it. What is wrong is actually setting the "window instanciation" logic into the ViewModel from a command (as a example). But by having a window manager.. i believe i am not actually doing this. I thought that i could have a method called ShowWindow that actually will call the window but that method get a string which is associated to a Window type in a list.. the mapping are done at a low level. There no way the ViewModel can know which window is called.

Comment: @Rushino: In Window Manager scenarios, the mapping is usually done based upon the type of the ViewModel being passed to it (i.e. you pass an instance of a ViewModel to the manager and it finds the right Window to display based upon its type) rather than a string. Other than that, you're right.

Comment: However, how the instance of a ViewModel know which window to display ?

Comment: @Rushino: It doesn't; the View layer does.